# Same function that will use different array for every unique class

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

Sorry if I messed up the title. I am not really sure how to correctly describe my case. I am still a beginner.

Anyway, I am trying to create a simple hover effect over the images that will display a word out of unique Array, change it to another and repeat every `.12s` - sort of flashing effect.

I will have 8 images at start, which means I will have to create 8 unique arrays.

The problem is that, to make everything work, I had to multiply same function for every individual image/unique class, which to me, seems a little messy, even though it works.

Here is a little example for two containers - hover over the grey areas:

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  
  var LP1 = [
  'ui',
  'ux',
  'webdesign',
  'logo',
  'responsive',
  'personal'
  ], i = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
  $('.left-title').fadeOut(0, function(){
  $(this).html(LP1[i=(i+1)%LP1.length]).fadeIn(0);
  });
  }, 120);
  
  var LP2 = [
  'cover',
  'art',
  'music',
  'print',
  'personal'
  ], i = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
  $('.right-title').fadeOut(0, function(){
  $(this).html(LP2[i=(i+1)%LP2.length]).fadeIn(0);
  });
  }, 120);
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap-fixed-real {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.left {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  background-color: #292929;
}
.right{
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  background-color: #292929;
}
.dimming {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.left-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.left:hover .dimming {
  opacity: .4;
}
.left:hover .left-title {
  opacity: 1;
}
.right-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.right:hover .dimming {
  opacity: .4;
}
.right:hover .right-title {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="left-title">LP1</div>
      <div class="dimming"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="right-title">LP2</div>
      <div class="dimming"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Sorry for the messy code. If it comes to css, I guess I could create 8 different subclasses and 1 unique that will share same styles but I have no clue how to force single function to use different array for every image/unique class. I was doing some research on the internet but I couldn't find an answer. Maybe I am just using wrrong keywords in google, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be nice. Or maybe creating what I want is possible, only by multiplying a function? I am not sure.

**Summary:** I want every unique Array to be connected with unique class and single function that will make "flashing inscription" effect happen.

There is also one more thing that I am not sure about. The effect that changes text every `.12s` will be played for 8 different images at a time. Is it going to slow down my website? Maybe in addition I should hide this effect at start, instead of just setting opacity to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a little jQuery plug-in for this:

```js
$.fn.flashWith = function (LP, delay) {
    setInterval(function(){
        this.fadeOut(0, function(){
            // cycle the given array as you get the first text
            $(this).text(LP.shift(LP.push(LP[0]))).fadeIn(0);
        });
    }.bind(this), delay);
    return this;
};

$(function() {
    $('.left-title').flashWith([
        'ui',
        'ux',
        'webdesign',
        'logo',
        'responsive',
        'personal'
    ], 120);

  $('.right-title').flashWith([
        'cover',
        'art',
        'music',
        'print',
        'personal'
    ], 120);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap-fixed-real {
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.left {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  background-color: #292929;
}
.right{
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% - 8px);
  background-color: #292929;
}
.dimming {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.left-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.left:hover .dimming {
  opacity: .4;
}
.left:hover .left-title {
  opacity: 1;
}
.right-title {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: opacity .24s 0s cubic-bezier(.64,0,.36,1);
}
.right:hover .dimming {
  opacity: .4;
}
.right:hover .right-title {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="left-title">LP1</div>
      <div class="dimming"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="right-title">LP2</div>
      <div class="dimming"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you good sir for taking your time. I appreciate it. I gotta admit though, I don't entirely understand how it actually works. I will do some research later on. For a now I am going to implement this. Thanks again! :)

Comment: You can read about creating plugins (i.e. defining some `$.fn.xxxx` function) at [jquery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).